# Setting unsigned int always zero in foreach style loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to loop a map of object's which contain a `unsigned int category` which I want to set to an enum value. The PlayerToon enum value is equal to 2.

Map Declaration :

```
std::map<Action, Command> _actionBindings;
```

Setting map values :

```
//Assign category to value of '2'
for (auto actionPair : _actionBindings)
{
   actionPair.second.category = Category::PlayerToon;  
}

//Outputs '0', expected '2'
std::cout << "Category " << _actionBindings[Action::MoveLeft].category << "\n";
```

On the other hand, if I explicitely replace the loop with manual affectation the value of my category is indeed '2' as expected :

```
_actionBindings[Action::MoveLeft].category = Category::PlayerToon;

//Outputs '2'
std::cout << "Category " << _actionBindings[Action::MoveLeft].category << "\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making copies of the map's elements here:

```
for (auto actionPair : _actionBindings)
```

Use references instead:

```
for (auto& actionPair : _actionBindings)
         ^
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that with the range-based loop. Makes sense.